# Would Superman's flight be damaging?

Tags: pressure, aerodynamics

I recently asked [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71821/how-does-superman-avoid-deafening-everyone-with-his-sonic-booms) on the effects of Superman's sonic booms and it's become clear that Physics.SE is better equipped to answer it. I'll set up some assumptions.

1. Superman's travelling to China to get some dinner. Using New York as a starting point, that's 11,851 km.
2. It's ten minutes each way. That excludes his acceleration, let's say constant for 10 seconds. That means he's travelling at 19.751 m/s.
3. He keeps a constant altitude of 500 metres.
4. He and his suit are invulnerable.

So my question is, what effects would this have on the environment as he passes through? Would it cause injury to people, or damage buildings?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about impossible things (e.g. *invulnerable*).

Comment: That makes it *theoretical* physics.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Isn't an invulnerable suit just as impossible as a frictionless surface or ideal gas or massless rope... Many posts are apparently off topic then.

Comment: "What effects would this have?" Effects on what? You said 'he and his suit are invulnerable,' which I assume means impervious to change, so it would have no effects...

Comment: @JamalS, edited to answer your question.

Comment: 19 km/s is the speed of the Chelyabinsk meteor

Comment: Superman, aware of the damage caused by sonic booms, executes a bunch of hand-wiggles while flying which cause destructive interference, disbursing the sonic "boom" wavefront within a few meters of himself.